# Rails/RSpec/FactoryGirl—How to make a field point to a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have this factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :gst_report do
    association :organisation, factory: :active_organisation
    period_months 3
    period_start_date Date.parse('2015-01-01')
    period_end_date Date.parse('2015-02-01')
  end
end
```

But in the tests `period_start_date` is often set to other dates. For each of these tests, I want `period_end_date` to simply be a month after `period_start_date`.

Is it possible to make `period_end_date` a method that gets the current `period_start_date` and adds one month to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the `period_end_date` to `period_start_date` plus a month by using [FactoryGirl Callbacks](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks)

This should work for your case:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :gst_report do
    association :organisation, factory: :active_organisation
    period_months 3
    period_start_date Date.parse('2015-01-01')

    after(:build) do |gst_report|
      gst_report.period_end_date = (gst_report.period_start_date + 1.month) unless gst_report.period_end_date
    end
  end
end
```

Note that `period_end_date` is not specified before hand. We're also only assigning the end date if it hasn't been specified when building the factory so that you can still specify different start/end periods through your specs.

Comment: Thanks for fixing up the code in that edit @XinruiZhu!